# PHP mysqli access denied, using IP instead of computer name

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to mysql and PHP.

I am trying to connect to a mysql server using:

```
define("USER", "mghandi");
define("HOST", "mysql-host");
define("DATABASE", "dbnam");
define("PASSWORD", "pass");
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

I get the following access denied error:

```
Access denied for user 'mghandi'@'abc12-345.mycompany.org' (using password: YES)
```

abc12-345 is my computer name.

I checked the accesses on mysql server using show GRANTS;

there is access granted for mghandi@67.890.%.%

my computer IP is  67.890.127.100  so I assume the problem is that mysqli is using my computer name rather than my computer IP address (so for example mghandi@67.890.127.100 would work but it is trying to connect as mghandi@abc12-345.mycompany.org) . How can I fix this problem?

EDIT:

The connection is via LAN. The mysql server is on a server (called 'mysql-host') on our company's network.

Comment: You don't show `HOST` being defined, but I would use 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Comment: no, use `localhost` not 127.0.0.1 (even though they're usually the same)

Comment: We need to know a little about the connection between yourself and the mysql server. Is it on a LAN or the internet? If it's on the LAN you need to use the internal IP of your host not the one facing the internet, and vice versa.

Comment: First thing I would try is flushing the privileges. If they were set by direct dml of the access tables then they are ignored by the server until the privileges are reloaded. I would also check logging in from a local host session if allowed, and make sure the passwords match.

Answer (score -1):

user set to server name
eg localhost. hostname is the name of server where you database is hosted. if you database is hosted locally use localhost

Comment: can you elaborate further pls.